# Needing ID for Greyhound Trip

Tags: usa, greyhound

The father of my child is in California, I'm sending him money to buy the ticket to come out to TN. He does not have his ID but has a birth certificate.

Will they ask for his ID if he buys the bus ticket? Or when he gets on the bus?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. It's not clear from your question whether *he* refers to the father or the child, but if the former, then *[How can I have “will call” Greyhound tickets picked up without a photo ID?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787)* might be informative.

Comment: For a bus ticket, I do not think ID is required.  He probably needs ID to get the money, though, depending on how you've sent it.  You shouldn't send cash through the mail.

Comment: You buying a bus ticket and then mailing it to him would seem to be the way to go. If you buy it online you may be able to get Greyhound to mail it straight to him. He won't need ID to get on the bus if he has a ticket.

Comment: How old is the father of your child?

Comment: Is your child with the father, or are we just talking about the father coming to visit?