# Traveling from El Paso, TX, to Tulsa, OK? No ID, but traveling companion has one

Tags: usa, paperwork, buses, identity-cards

I need to get to Tulsa, OK, from El Paso, TX. I don't have an ID, but my boyfriend, who will be traveling with me and whose aunt will be paying for the trip, has a current ID. What are my options? I only have a Social Security card and a health insurance policy document.

Comment: Where are you traveling from?

Comment: El paso texas that's where I'm at

Comment: You're looking to take the bus? Greyhound has a mechanism for where your aunt can buy the tickets and you can pick them up with a password instead of an ID. We have [an answer about that here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787/how-can-i-have-will-call-greyhound-tickets-picked-up-without-a-photo-id) already.

Comment: That said, you might consider getting a photo ID if you are able to do so, as it will make many activities significantly easier, such as flying.

Comment: She don't have anofe for gray hound she just got done paying her house

Comment: She doesn't have enough money for Greyhound? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: What kind of I'd  can I use all I have is my ssc and my helth insurance card and bills in my name

Comment: Yes I am I'm just upset and being pregnant  don't help than I'm trying to text fast

Comment: She can buy you a Greyhound bus ticket and you can pick it up without ID. She needs to buy a [gift ticket order](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787/how-can-i-have-will-call-greyhound-tickets-picked-up-without-a-photo-id) with Greyhound and then can give you a special password you can use to pick the ticket up instead of showing ID.

Comment: How much would that be for two people

Comment: You'd have to search on [greyhound.com](http://greyhound.com) for the exact dates, but around $168/person for a round trip if you book in advance. It's also going to take around 16-20 hours. A flight looks like it's around $340/person for the round-trip in the next month or two, but you're supposed to need [valid ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) for that (price varies a lot depending on the dates too). If that's too expensive, perhaps you can find someone who is driving that route and wants passengers, maybe on [craigslist](http://craigslist.org)?

Comment: @ZachLipton I think that last comment is probably enough for an answer. Perhaps the question should be edited to something like "Cheapest way to travel from El Paso, TX, to Tulsa, OK, with no ID?"

Answer (score 5):

It seems you want to travel by bus. [Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/) has a mechanism called a "gift ticket order" where your aunt can purchase tickets for you, and you can pick them up by giving only a password, no ID required. We have [an answer all about that here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787/how-can-i-have-will-call-greyhound-tickets-picked-up-without-a-photo-id), and you can contact Greyhound for specific assistance using their website to book tickets.

To answer your further questions, it looks like bus tickets for two people from El Paso to Tulsa will cost around $168/person for a round-trip if you book in advance. You'll need to search on their website for the exact price, as it depends on what days you want to travel. The trip will also take 16-20 hours each way and requires several transfers.

In contrast, a flight will cost more like $340/person for a round-trip, but prices vary significantly depending on when you want to travel, so you'll have to search for that yourself. To fly, you will need [one of these forms of ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), however. But if you're eligible for an ID and are able to get the required documents together, you could get an ID, which would be useful in many situations.

If Greyhound is too expensive, you could perhaps find someone who happens to be driving that way and is willing to take passengers, possibly for gas money, on a website like [Craigslist](http://craigslist.org/).