# Is bus travel in with expired photo ID possible in the US?

Tags: usa, paperwork, buses

Trying to get a friend to Oregon. His ID is expired but does have a photo of him. Is it still possible for him to pick up a bus ticket using this ID?

Comment: Did you contact the bus company and ask it?

Comment: Is this Greyhound or another bus company?

Comment: If you're asking possible, it is very very possible. I have done things with an expired ID because the checkers didn't bother with the date. If the question however is that is it valid for picking up, no it is not.

Answer (score 12):

Although the question didn't specifically mention Greyhound, this is Greyhound's policy and I assume should be similar for other bus transport organizations in this time of increased vigilance due to terrorism.

[Greyhound Official Response](https://m.facebook.com/GreyhoundBus/posts/596338027076141) from their Facebook account:

> A Valid State Issued ID may range from a passport to a driver's
>   license. **An expired ID may not be accepted**. If you are to purchase
>   a *Will Call Ticket*, you can create a password for the traveler to
>   use as ID. A nonrefundable gift ticket fee is applied to each Will
>   Call transaction where the credit card holder purchasing tickets is
>   not traveling on that trip. However, printed at ­home tickets along
>   with valid photo ID will be required at point of origin.

[How can I have "will call" Greyhound tickets picked up without a photo ID?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787/how-can-i-have-will-call-greyhound-tickets-picked-up-without-a-photo-id?rq=1)

Comment: It seems unlikely that terrorism is the issue, since AFAICT you can avoid showing any ID by using the password option, or simply buying your ticket on site with cash.  More likely it's just to avoid having your ticket stolen by someone else who knows you bought it.